# Where are the first two waypoints for runway 4R departures from KBOS?

Tags: navigation, sid-star

Departure way points for Runway 4R at Logan Airport in Boston Massachusetts. Can anyone send me a map depicting where the first 2 way-points are for 4R Departures?

Comment: This is going to be dependent upon the specific departure chosen or assigned by ATC.  Which departure are you flying?

Comment: @CarloFelicione All departures from 4R have NHANT and HURBE as the first two waypoints.

Answer (score 4):

Checking the [IFR departure plates for KBOS](http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/KBOS/procedures), the first two waypoints for all departures from Runway 4R are NHANT and HURBE. You can see where they are on the Google map below.

[BLZZR THREE departure plate](http://flightaware.com/resources/airport/BOS/DP/BLZZR+THREE+(RNAV)/pdf) for reference.

[image]

Comment: `the first two waypoints for all departures from Runway 4R are NHANT and HURBE` <— This is not strictly true. This does appear to be true for all RNAV based departures with departures specifically listed for 4R (those with waypoints) but is not true for the [Logan Two](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1711/pdf/00058LOGAN_C.PDF) which calls for headings to DME distance.